# Альтернатива map-remove в scss?

Tags: bootstrap, scss

Есть способ не указывать то, что нужно удалить, а наоборот — указывать то, что нужно оставить? То есть, если мне нужно оставить 1 цвет, то зачем мне указывать 7 цветов которые нужно удалить, когда можно было бы указать 1 который нужно оставить.

Плюс, [нашел в исходниках](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/scss/bootstrap-grid.scss#L29) комментарий "Only use the utilities we need". Но на деле удалить через map-remove неиспользованные утилиты у меня не получилось. Можно небольшой пример?

**variables.scss**

```
@import "~bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/mixins";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/utilities";

$colors: map-remove($colors, 
    "blue",
    "indigo",
    "purple",
    "pink",
    "red",
    "orange",
    "yellow",
    "green",
    "teal",
    "cyan",
    "white",
    "gray",
    "gray-dark"
);

$theme-colors: map-remove($theme-colors,
    "primary",
    "secondary",
    "success",
    "info",
    "warning",
    "danger",
    "light"
);

@import "~bootstrap/scss/root";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/reboot";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/grid";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/buttons";
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно написать свою мжвячную сочную функцию:

```
@function map-subset($map, $keys...) {
  $subset: ();
  @each $key in $keys {
    $subset: map-merge($subset, ($key: map-get($map, $key)));
  }
  @return $subset;
}

$colors: map-subset($colors, 
  "deep",
  "purple",
  "pink",
  "floyd"
);
```